# SSRS: run queries before and after execution

Tags: reporting-services

Trying to use two DB functions that should run before and after running a report: SetConnection and EndConnection.

Is there a way to make this happen?
I've tried adding them as first and last datasets, respectively, but it doesn't always work unfortunately, though I've set the single transaction mode on the data source.
Is there a way to get around this?

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [SSRS pre- and postrendering events](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22167136/ssrs-pre-and-postrendering-events)

Answer (score 0):

Please try adding your functions to the primary data set. Example, if you are using a stored procedure then the functions can be added as part of the stored procedure code.

Comment: What is a primary data set?